# Where do I find the memory requirements of a MATLAB function?

Tags: matlab, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a 3D array of values (0 or 1), which is very large (approx 2300x2300x11). I want to fit a surface to these values using for example `interp3`, but when I try MATLAB runs out of memory. Thus, I've decided to reduce the size of my array enough for MATLAB to accomodate it in memory.

Now, the smaller I make the reduced array, the worse my results will be (the surface fitting is part of a measurement process with high precision requirements), so I want to reduce the array as little as possible.

Is there any way to determine on beforehand how much memory a certain array size will demand and how much memory is available, and then use this information to resize the array enough to avoid out of memory exceptions, but not more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [the maximum array sizes that are supported on different platforms](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1110.html). In general, if you have a `PxQxR` sized 3D array of `double`s, then the size of your array in bytes is `P*Q*R*8`. For your matrix, the size is ~ 444 MB. You can also try reducing it to a `single`, using `single(A)`. `single` uses 4 bytes per element and you can reduce the size of your array by a factor 2.

I haven't really poked into the inner workings of `interp3`, but the exact memory requirements will depend on the interpolation option you choose. So, you can first try to convert it to `single` and see if it works. If not, try with 80% (90%) of the number of rows and columns. This way you have a good chunk of the original array, but the memory requirement is only 64% (81%) of the original.

If that doesn't help, duffymo's suggestion is what you should be looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to this, but I wonder if you can have your cake and eat it, too.

If your data set is too big, why not do a piecewise fit?  Do it in chunks rather than omitting data points.

Or be smarter about how you omit data points.  You want them in areas of high curvature - where your data is changing fastest.  Leave out points in areas far away from the action, where nothing interesting is happening.  You might have to do a fit, look at the surface, add and remove more points and try again.

It might an iterative process, but I'll bet you'll be able to get a nice fit with a little luck and effort.